# How to use google api to sign up in python?

Tags: python, authentication, google-apps-script

I am building a login application in python and kivy. So far, I have created a database and the signup is possible. I want to be able to sign up with a google account. What and how can I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Sign-In For Websites for this. Please see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.

Comment: But this is for a web application using javascript. Kivy is used for a desktop application. :)

Comment: although kivy can be used for desktop applications. if you are building any serious application pyqt or tkinter will be better supported as kivy only runs on opengl. in addition to that the above answer should be accepted, I dont know what the current flavor of python http request library looks like. but im fairly certain any of them are compatible with the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a Desktop Application and that you want to authenticate via a Google Account, I suggest you to follow the steps specified here: [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#obtainingaccesstokens).